# Python check value of key in element and return element in list

Tags: python, list, object

I have a json file, and I'm reading this file with `json` library

This is the json content (example)

```
{
  "type": "champion",
  "format": "standAloneComplex",
  "version": "10.18.1",
  "data": {
    "Aatrox": {
      "version": "10.18.1",
      "id": "Aatrox",
      "key": "266",
      "name": "Aatrox"
    },
    "Ahri": {
      "version": "10.18.1",
      "id": "Ahri",
      "key": "103",
      "name": "Ahri",
    },
}
```

Now how can I check if `key` is equal to 266 and return the value of `name`?

I was trying with something like this

```
import json
with open('./source/champion.json') as json_file:
    data_champs = json.load(json_file)['data']
    for champ in data_champs:
        for champ_info in data_champs[champ]:
            if champ['key'] == 266:
                print(champ)
```

But return TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
import json


with open('./source/champion.json') as json_file:
    for name, info in json.load(json_file)['data'].items():
        if info['key'] == 266:
            print(name)
```

Or even better, we can close the file after we get the data and not keep it open during processing:

```py
import json


with open('./source/champion.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)['data']

for name, info in data.items():
    if info['key'] == 266:
        print(name)
```

#### Explanation

The easiest way to iterate over a `dict`'s elements is by using its `.items()` method:

```py
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key, "-->", value)
```

Answer (score 2):

below (iterating over the values only since the keys are not important here)

```
import json

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)['data']
    for v in data.values():
        if v['key'] == '266':
            print(v['name'])
            break
```

output

```
Aatrox
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
import json
with open('champion.json') as json_file:
    data_champs = json.load(json_file)['data']
    for data in data_champs.keys():
        if data_champs[data]['key']=='266':
            print(data_champs[data]['name'])
```

Prints:

```
Aatrox
```